# How to not use Rails action parameter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing a third party API for Shipworks in a Rails server and the Shipworks client app is posting an `action` param with Shipworks specific semantics.

However the Rails routing logic overwrites this param to be the name of the controller method.

Is there a custom route I could write to get the value of that action param without it being overwritten to be the name of my controller method?

Answer (score 17):

I fell into this trap today and came with this solution in controller method. It's Rails 4.1:

```
if request.method == "POST"
  action = request.request_parameters['action']
else
  action = request.query_parameters['action']
end
```

Comment: You saved me! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  There is a `raw_post` method in [AbstractRequest](http://docs.huihoo.com/api/ruby-on-rails/classes/ActionController/AbstractRequest.html#M000227).

So you can do this to parse the raw post params:

```
def raw_post_to_hash
  request.raw_post.split(/&/).inject({}) do |hash, setting|
    key, val = setting.split(/=/)
    hash[key.to_sym] = val
    hash
   end
end
```

and then just call raw_post_to_hash[:action] to access the original action param or any other param.  There is probably an easier way.

Comment: Why not use `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query` to parse this string?