# Rails "action" params key conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I am building a RESTful Rails service with various CRUD endpoints. On one of the Create endpoints, the data I am passing in includes:

```
...
action: "action_name"
...
```

The problem I am having is that `params[:action]` contains "create", not the actual value of the `action` parameter I'm passing in. This, I assume, is because `params[:action]` is being populated by Rails automatically.

Is there another way to access this key I am passing in? Am I doing something blatantly stupid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its awkward to use this, but if ever its required, you can get the info using:

```
 request.POST
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. According to [How to not use Rails action parameter in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209848/how-to-not-use-rails-action-parameter-in-controller) , you can get it by:

```
if request.method == "POST"
  action = request.request_parameters['action']
else
  action = request.query_parameters['action']
end
```