# Conflict on 'action' parameter with controller action name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have an API endpoint that handles requests from a third-party app. The problem is that the 3rd-party application sends out a parameter named 'action', and in rails, params[:action] is equivalent to the action name of the API endpoint.

How do I retrieve the actual value of the 'action' parameter that was sent from the request?

The endpoint by the way is a POST method. I tried

> request.POST['action']

and/or

> request.request_parameters['action']

but the 'action' key is not present.

Comment: Just googled [this](http://status203.me/2015/02/16/rails-edge-case-solved-with-middleware/)

Comment: duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207671/rails-action-params-key-conflict