# In Rails Controller testing, is there a way to pass action parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

> ### NOTE
>
> I know, that `action` is reserved word in Rails. I am implementing a third party API for Yandex Money in a Rails server and the Yandex API app is posting an `action` param into my Rails application. I know how get it ([How to not use Rails action parameter in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209848/how-to-not-use-rails-action-parameter-in-controller)). The issue is - how write test to my controller, because my test can't send `action` parameter (see description below).

I'm writing controller tests in Rails, and I need pass `action` parameters to the controller from test. This is my controller:

```
class YandexController < ApplicationController
  def notify
    render text: request.request_parameters
  end
end
```

When I POST data with `curl` command:

```
curl --data "action=paymentAviso&some_other_param=value" http://localhost:3000/yandex/notify
```

I get correct result:

```
{"action"=>"paymentAviso", "some_other_param"=>"value"}
```

But when I try send `action` parameter in test then it is not working. See my test below:

```
class YandexControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "notify sucess" do
    post :notify, { action: 'paymentAviso', some_other_param: 'value' }
    assert_response :success
    puts response.body
  end
end
```

And when I run test I see:

> Running:
>
> {"some_other_param"=>"value"}

Is there a way to pass `action` parameter to my controller from test?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4673459/1657377

Comment: @jethroo I know about it, please read `NOTE` section in my question

Comment: Did you implement the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209848/how-to-not-use-rails-action-parameter-in-controller ? If so, update your code

Comment: @WesFoster I updated my question with new code

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `action` in the params unless you are referring to a controller's action. The `action` parameter is what Rails uses to determine which method to run in the controller. Therefore, when you run your spec, it's just calling `paymentAdviso` in the controller.

You should change the parameter name so that it does not interfere with Rails' conventions.

For a list of other reserved Rails words, look here: https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Yes, I understand that is reserved word, but I need integrate with external payment system, that pass `action` parameter in POST request. That is why I must use this parameter name.

Comment: You can simply pass `payment_action` to your controller, then take that value and pass it as `action` to your external payment system. You can't argue with Rails :)